# Eager loading property of derived class using Include

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first

I have classes like:

```
Person
{
   Name
   Address
}

Employee : Person
{
   Compensation - object
}

Visitor : Person
{

}
```

If I write linq:

```
var persons = Context.Persons
                .Include("Compensation");
```

I get error:

> A specified Include path is not valid.
>   The EntityType 'Person' does not
>   declare a navigation property with the
>   name 'Compensation'.

It works ok if I do:

```
var persons = Context.Persons
                .OfType<Employee>()
                .Include("Compensation");
```

But I would like to get Employees and visitors in the same query.

Looks like there is a request for this feature on EF4 UserVoice:
http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1249289-include-property-of-derived-classes?ref=title

but it does not look like it will get done any time soon.

What is a good workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 7):

You can try it this way:

```
var persons = Context.Persons
                     .OfType<Employee>()
                     .Include("Compensation")
                     .Concat<Person>(Context.Persons.OfType<Visitor>());
```

Comment: Change concat line to: .Concat<Person>(Context.Persons.OfType<Visitor>());  otherwise does not compile.  When running still get the same error as in original question.

Comment: @Ladislav, In my scenario, the `Person` type isn't abstract, there are entities that are just `Person` neither `Employee` or `Visitor`. Your example won't give me those **`Person`**s. Trying to combine `Person` query causes the exception reported by the OP. Any workarounds will be really appreciated (in my case it's not `Person`, it's `Transaction` but whatever).

Comment: @Shimmy: Ask a separate question with example of the problem and reference this one. Comments are not well suited for solving another (even similar) problem.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka, I thought to but I don't want ppl to mark it as dup. Anyway [here you go](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9479763/75500).

Comment: Hey there Ladislav. I've tried this suggestion in my scenario and it is not working. I get an exception saying that `Profile does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Profiles'`. I've created a new question with my requirements [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331779/how-do-i-perform-eager-loading-of-a-property-on-a-derived-type-in-a-query-for-th). Could you take a look at that?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a nice example of how to load `Persons` and include `Compensation` for `Employees`

Replace `Reference()` by `Collection()` for a collection property.

```
IQueryable<Person> GetPersons()
{
    var persons = Context.Persons;
    foreach(var entry in persons.OfType<Employee>())
        Context.Entry(entry).Reference(e => e.Compensation).Load();
    return persons;
}
```

Not sure either if it's efficient, but it works, and the intention is clearer than with joins.

Based on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19961187/2498426)

Comment: Worked for me, had to replace Reference with Collection though, since my property was a collection.

Answer (score 2):

```
var employees = context.Persons.OfType<Employee>().Include(x => x.Compensation).ToArray();

var nonEmployees = context.Persons.Except(context.Persons.OfType<Employee>()).ToArray();

var people = employees.Concat(nonEmployees);
```

Answer (score 0):

This horrible thing works:

```
var persons = context.Persons
                .Concat(context.Employees
                    .Where(e => e.Compensation.Amount >= 0))
                .Concat(context.Visitors
                    .Where(v => v.SomeProperty == "AlwaysTrue"));
```

I'm not sure why, but when you filter on an object property, the property's object is eagerly loaded. If you don't want to filter that property, then use a condition that will always be true.

*Disclaimer: I have no idea how efficient the resulting query is. I checked the sql generated when I tested this in a slightly more complicated scenario and it was very very large.*

Comment: This is crazy... I'm trying to make this work but my navigation property is a collection. Any ideas on that? Everything I've tried still doesn't load the collection.