# Is it possible to eager load a property with inheritance on EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following classes:

```
public class Box
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Toy : Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ElectricToy
    : Toy
{
    public int Voltage { get; set; }
}

public class WoodenToy
    : Toy
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

A Box has a collection of items which might be electric toys or wooden toys. Now, I want to load all toys in a box with the following code.

```
var boxes = 
    db.Boxes
        .Where(o => o.Id = id)
        .Include(o => o.Items);
```

It loads all toy but it doesn't load electric and wooden toy values, that is Voltage is always 0 and Color is always null.

How to force Entity Framework to load values for ElectricToy and WoodenToy?

Comment: @SAm yes, it is. I just updated code sample. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263288/eager-loading-property-of-derived-class-using-include

Comment: @dotNET No, it isn't. That question wants to download a specific type from DbSet<Type> while I want to download all properties of subtype of a property of DbSet<Type>. Entity's structure is difference.

Comment: If it's one level inheritance then everything is fine. I only face this problem when it has multiple-level of inheritance.